# Moq Tests pass when runs individually but not when the whole test class runs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, moq

Why does my test fails, if I run it besides others (whole test class) but always pass if I run it individually. The same behavior with other test, which contains also two calls to HttpClientMock. They always exists with error *Expected invocation on the mock exactly 2 times, but was 1 times: mock => mock.SendAsync(It.Is(req => req.Method == POST), It.IsAny())*

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
     // Arrange
     ...
     HttpRequestMessage firstRequestMessage = null;
     _factory.HttpClientMock.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                        "SendAsync",
                        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.Method == HttpMethod.Post && x.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/FirstCall")),
                        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                    .ReturnsAsync((HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token) =>
                    {
                        firstRequestMessage = message;
                        return new HttpResponseMessage
                        {
                            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                            Content = JsonContent.Create(new ResponseCall1())
                    
                        };
                    });
     _factory.HttpClientMock.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                        "SendAsync",
                        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.Method == HttpMethod.Post && x.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/SecondCall")),
                        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                    .ReturnsAsync((HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token) => new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        Content = JsonContent.Create(new ResponseCall2())
                    
                    });
      var client = _factory.CreateClient();
            
      // Act
      await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/Init", new object {});
                
      // Assert
      _factory.HttpClientMock.Protected().Verify(
                                "SendAsync",
                                Times.Exactly(2),
                                ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Post),
                                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
      Assert.NotNull(customerRequestMessage);
      ...
```

Comment: to be honest it is a bad test, too much code. Did you debug this test?

Comment: Without looking at the code, I predict you have state that is not being properly reset by each test.

Comment: @zolty13 I share your opinion that it is too much code. I will refactor it once the test pass.  Yes, I've debugged the test but because the fact that the test only fail if I run multiple tests, the debugging is difficult. If I get the error in the introduction the line firstRequestMessge = message; will processed. If I changed the Times.Exactly(2) to (1) this line will no longer executed at all. Then I get of course the error Assert.NotNull() Failure

Comment: @Richard I'm using xUnit, and always call _factory.HttpClientMock.Invocations.Clear(); to cleanup the past executions. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Based on the symptoms: probably not. Try two tests that completely set up fresh state: no shared instances.